# How to shutdown the host (ubuntu) inside a docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, shutdown, docker-privileged

I would like to shutdown the machine (host) when the docker container finishes a job.

My host OS is Ubuntu.

The container can run as `--privileged=true`. That is not a problem.

I managed to do this with the command (found in a stackoverflow answer):

```
subprocess.run("echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq; echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger", shell=True, check=True)
```

The problem with this approach it is immediate, unclean shutdown in Linux.

If I try a clean way as a `shutdown now`, I get the following error: `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.`

How can I use shutdown or halt or other alternative within my container to shutdown the host?

Comment: You don't need a subprocess and a shell to open two pseudofiles and write to them.

Comment: `with open('/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq', 'w') as sysrq, open('/proc/sysrq-trigger') as trigger: sysrq.write('1\n'); trigger.write('o\n')`

Answer (score 8):

For your specific case to perform a shutdown once the docker exits mikey's solution is simple and elegant.

For a more generic case, like with a bunch of dockerized micro-services with one needing to be able to shut down or reboot the host, the following approach can be used:

In systemd systems like recent Debian or Ubuntu, the `shutdown`/`halt`/`poweroff`/`reboot` commands are just symlinks to `systemctl` and it is possible to run for example `systemctl halt` instead of just `halt`.

So the issue becomes to perform `systemctl` commands on the host from within a docker container. This can be achieved mapping some volumes like in the following command:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /bin/systemctl:/bin/systemctl -v /run/systemd/system:/run/systemd/system -v /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket:/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup debian:10 systemctl --no-pager status
```

With these volumes mapped, you can then just execute a `systemctl poweroff` from within the docker and the host will shut down and power off.

Comment: The example command in my case returns `Failed to read server status: Access denied` unless I add `--privileged`.

Comment: That's well possible. In my case i didn't need `--privileged`, tried it both running root or an user inside the container. To be honest i was surprised it worked withoug it. But probably on many systems it is needed.

Comment: Hah I love it, that's really cool. Have you had to expose the host systemd to containers before?

Comment: No, it's the first time.

Comment: Works perfectly for me with `--privileged`.  Allows me to reboot the host machine from the Portainer web interface, which means I don't need an open SSH connection to my server (or to hook up a keyboard and monitor).

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm missing an unspecified constraint, I can't see why you couldn't do this on the host from a shell:

- `docker run image_name; shutdown now`

This would required the Dockerfile to end in a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` command, which specifies the script.

Once the script within the container finishes, the docker run process will end, and the shell can move onto the next command which is `shutdown now`.